# Getting error while trying to convert a string into a large number

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error while trying to save a large number which is converted from a string value, I know its larger than CUnsignedLongLong but is there any method to solve this issue?

```
var strVal = "999999999999999999999"
var n : CUnsignedLongLong = CUnsignedLongLong(strVal)! // Getting error on this line
```

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: for handling large numeric values , store data into array and create custom method to perform arithmetic , we cant use outside value :i.e - min and max value provided by any data type

Comment: Take a look at `NSDecimalNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You got error because it is out of the bounds of `CUnsignedLongLong`.
Max value of `CUnsignedLongLong` is `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`
and you trying to assign value `999,999,999,999,999,999,999`

Comment: Yes, I know that but i need a solution over this issue

Comment: @Jan then you only need to google for bigger data type...

Comment: @Jan anywhere your question was not about this. And you may try that library - https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp

Comment: If you don't declare an explicit type, Swift will infer it. @Jan

Comment: @PavelGatilov yeah, checked it out and seems to be very good approach